# Getting a value Error : how to use string data type in model.fit for jupyter using DecisionTreeClassifier?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

this is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dataset = pd.read_csv("emotion.csv")
X = dataset.drop(columns = ["mood"])
y = dataset['mood']
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
model.predict([["i am sad"]])
```

and this is the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'oh yeah'
```

any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Pls share sample data for emotion.csv. Also, where is the ````fit```` model line? How will you be able to predict before fitting?

Comment: @Redox I think it is a misprint, and line `model.(X,y)` looks like it should be `model.fit(X,y)`.

Comment: yes it was a mistake while pasting on stack overflow I fixed it but still it isn't working

Comment: @011000110110111101101111011 There's an edit button underneath your question, provide the most recent, relevant code so it's easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Feature engineering

You can't use raw features represented with strings in `DecisionTreeClassifier`. You have to train your decision tree on the data represented with numbers. `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'oh yeah'` means that decision tree tried to take `float()` of values in your data to convert them to numbers for you, but did not succeed.

If you have categorical features - process them with some encoding method: for instance, label encoding, one hot encoding. You can read more about categorical features encoding methods in many different sources, e.g. [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/benchmarking-categorical-encoders-9c322bd77ee8).

If you have text features - use feature extraction methods to generate new features based on them: for instance, TF-IDF. Again, you can find many materials on it, e.g. [methods overview in `scikit-learn` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html).

## Example

Here is an example on how to work with data represented only with text. I suggest you to study TF-IDF technique and [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) documentation page to understand better what is happening.

Data: https://github.com/dair-ai/emotion_dataset/blob/master/README.md

Code:

```
import pickle
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

with open('merged_training.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5, max_features=1000)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['text'])
y = data['emotions']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=13)
model.fit(X, y)

accuracy_score(y, model.predict(X))
```

Output:

```
0.3708941025745605
```

Please notice that **this is just a starter** and it has many things to improve. For instance:

- Separate train and validation data set
- Preprocess input text
- Try other models, such as logistic regression or boosting
- tune hyperparameters

I hope this gives you an idea on what you can do with text data.

Comment: hi ! thank for the reply but I'm new and I only understood half of the things you said. I basically just want the model to predict the emotion by giving it a string ,how would I do that?

Comment: @011000110110111101101111011 Hello! I have updated my answer and added an example which might give you better understanding about what you can do with text data.